# How to watch a variable in angular component?

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools, augury

I have a variable elapsedTime, initialized in the constructor as `0`. I am watching it in Chrome devtools debugger as `this.elapsedTime`. It is initialized correctly. I also put a breakpoint in a method that will use this variable.

Angular goes on, does its thing, loads different components and the watched variable becomes `NaN`. I suppose the context of `this` is getting lost.

How to do this correctly?

Here is the snippet for the code -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-game-control",
  templateUrl: "./game-control.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./game-control.component.css"]
})
export class GameControlComponent implements OnInit {
  startTime: number;
  elapsedTime: number;
  clock: any;
  constructor() {
    this.startTime = new Date().getTime();
    this.elapsedTime = 0; // Correctly displays as initialized to 0 in watch variables
    this.clock = setInterval(this.startTimer, 1000);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  startTimer() {
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    // debugger;
    this.elapsedTime = currentTime - this.startTime; // place breakpoint here
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the method that uses the elapsedTime variable.

Comment: Also tell us more about the problem you are facing.

Comment: Show some code snippet too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be issue with the context (`this`), because you have called `this.startTime` function directly by passing its reference. Since you have passed reference of `this.startTime` inside `setInterval` it is considered `this` as `window` object. And modify `elapsedTime` and put it inside `window`(this) object.

To fix this issue you can call this.startTimer method from the callback function of setInterval like below.

```
this.clock = setInterval(() => this.startTimer(), 1000);
```

OR change `startTimer` function to `Arrow function` to keep `this` intact.

```
startTimer = () => {
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    // debugger;
    this.elapsedTime = currentTime - this.startTime; // place breakpoint here
}
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvbrx5?)